# Unresolved reference of default_web_client_id using google-services 4.3.9

Tags: android

When I use the `4.3.9` version of `google-services`, I have an unresolved reference on `R.string.default_web_client_id`. I don't have this problem if I use the 4.3.8 version. Why ?

Gradle :

```
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9"
```

Error :

> Unresolved reference: default_web_client_id

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem, it may be a bug so I just downgraded to version `4.3.8` and works as expected. Will do further research if version `4.4.0` doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

4.3.10 version is already available. It fixed the problem.

Comment: no sorry, I have the same problem with the 4.3.10 :/